# Combination of Int value

Tags: c, char, int

I'm working on a program which get a int value, applies it to the int.
Lets say that the value the user entered is 803. Then

```
int x = 803;
```

My problem is to convert the int into 1 char ineteger, like that.

```
x is 803
x is 8+3 (11 - it's not one char length)
x is 1+1 (2 - one char length);
```

another e.g:

```
x is 97
x is 9+7 (16 - not one char)
x is 1+6 (7 - one char)
```

I've tried many ways, like using while loops, converting into string and then to char array, and i can't find a solution.

Please help, Thanks in advance, sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: which language? please tag the language

Comment: Please post your best solution so far, we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I'm adding the C tag to this, as I think that's what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sum up the digits of an integer you could use the modulo-operator ('%' in most languages).

Pseudocode:

```
int sumUpDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    int tmp = (number > 0) ? number : (-1 * number);
    while (tmp > 0) {
        sum += tmp % 10;
        tmp = tmp / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: It's not a homework assignment... I don't learn C# at school.
It's in C#

And that's what I've done so far
http://pastebin.com/H0X1dZSH

it's not even close to what i want, i get 104 and not 2.

Comment: AlexS - the code is not working good enough, actually it partly working, the answer it replies to 803 is 11, and i wanted 2 (1+1 - the num are taken from 11) but thanks anyway i'll try to found my question with that

Comment: See this [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ww9t2871.aspx): Convert.ToInt32(char c) Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: You'll have to call this function on the result again, as long as `sum > 9`.